# What does make me nervous?

Tags: comprehension, reading

*The hallway is eerily empty when I exit the elevator, which always makes me nervous.*
Which does make me nervous, The hall way, The hall way being empty or the elevator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though the grammar is a little bit unclear, it really sounds like it's the act of exiting the elevator is what always makes you nervous. You see, relative pronouns such as *which* usually refer to the antecedent that's closest to them. In your sentence, it looks like the antecedent closest to the relative pronoun *which* is *when I exit the elevator*. Your sentence with respect to that pronoun structurally would be very similar to the following example:

> It's when I enter the kitchen, which always makes me hungry.

There is no other antecedent except for *when I enter the kitchen* that *which* could possibly be referring to. That's why it's the act of entering the kitchen is that which always makes me hungry.

Comment: I kind of agree with you on grammatical grounds but not on semantic ones.  The sentence has to be interpreted in context, and it doesn't really make sense to me to think that the writer refers to the hallway being *eerily empty* because simply the act of *exiting the elevator* makes him nervous!  If the writer is emphasizing the eery emptiness, it would make sense that that's what makes him nervous.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I totally agree with you on all points, but it does sound like **which** is tied to the idea of exiting the elevator rather than the hallway being eerily empty.